# Cómo establecer valores desde un menú con distintas clases

Tags: java

Estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación he encontrado algunos problemas y espero que me puedan ayudar.
estoy en java  realizando un ejercicio llamado clase canción, y clase CD, he implementado un método `main` para realizar un menú aparte fuera de estas dos clases. el método que uso para el menú es el `switch`; cuando llamo un método de la clase CD que contiene un `ArrayList` establezco los valores que vienen de entrada.

Pero a la hora de imprimir los valores que necesito desde el menú no me aparece nada.
la pregunta es como hago para que me devuelva los valores que digite anteriormente. porque cuando ejecuto el programa no me devuelve ningún valor pero tampoco me da error.
este es mi código:

```
package ejercicio12;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class main {
    public static void main(String[]args){


        CD canciones = new CD();
        String tema; 
        String compositor;
        int numero;
        int opcion;



        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        do{

            System.out.print("Ejercicio Cancion\n");
            System.out.println("1. Agregar Cancion");
            System.out.println("2. Ver cantidad de canciones");
            System.out.println("3. Numero de la cancion (ver cancion en esa posicion)");
            System.out.println("4.Grabar cancion en la posicion deseada");
            System.out.println("5. Eliminar cancion en la posicion indicada ");
            System.out.println("6. Salir ");
            System.out.println("Digite su opcion: ");
            opcion = sc.nextInt();
            switch (opcion){
                case 1: 
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("AGREGAR CANCION");
                    System.out.print("Nombre de la cancion: ");
                    tema = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Cancion guardada!!!!\n");
                    System.out.print("Nombre del autor: ");
                    compositor = sc.nextLine();
                    canciones.agregarCancion(tema, compositor);
                    System.out.print("Autor guardado!!!");       
                break;
                case 2:
                    canciones.numeroCanciones();
                break; 
                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Numero de la cancion");
                    numero = sc.nextInt();
                    canciones.dameCancion(numero).dameTitulo();
                break;
                case 4:
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Posicion que desea para la nueva cancion");
                    numero = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Nombre de la cancion: ");
                    tema = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Nombre del autor: ");
                    compositor = sc.nextLine();
                    Cancion p2 = new Cancion(tema, compositor);
                    canciones.grabaCancion(numero, p2);
                break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.print("Posicion en la que desea elimar la 
                    cancion");
                    numero = sc.nextInt();
                    canciones.elimina(numero);
                break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.close();
                default :
                    System.out.print("OPCION ERRONEA");
            }System.out.println();
        }while (opcion != 6);
```

Esta es la clase CD

```
package ejercicio12;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CD {


    //Atributos

    ArrayList <Cancion> canciones;

    private int contador;

    //Constructor de la lista canciones

    public CD(){
        canciones = new ArrayList  ();
    } 

    //devuelve el valor del contador de canciones

    public int numeroCanciones()
    {
        contador = canciones.size() + 1;
        return contador;
    }        

    //devuelve la cancion que se encuentra en la posicion indicada

    public Cancion dameCancion(int posicion)
    {
        return canciones.get(posicion);
    }

    //cambia la cancion de la posicion indicada por la nueva cancion proporcionada

    public void grabaCancion(int posicion, Cancion nuevaCancion)
    {
        canciones.add(posicion,nuevaCancion);
    }

    //agrega al final del array la cancion proporcionada

    public void agrega(Cancion nuevaCancion)
    {
        canciones.add(nuevaCancion);
    }

    //elimina la cancion que se encuentra en la posicion indicada

    public void elimina(int posicion)
    {
        canciones.remove(posicion);
    }

    public void agregarCancion(String titulo, String autor)
    {
        Cancion c1 = new Cancion(titulo, autor);
        canciones.add(c1);
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase `Cancion`

```
package ejercicio12;

public class Cancion {


    private String titulo;
    private String autor;

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public Cancion(String titulo, String autor) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public Cancion() {
        this.titulo = " ";
        this.autor = " ";
    }

    public String dameTitulo() {
        return this.titulo;

    }

    public String dameAutor() {
        return this.autor;
    }

    public void ponTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;

    }

    public void ponAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es muy sencillo , no se muestra porque no está imprimiendo el valor.

```
public int numeroCanciones()
{
    contador = canciones.size() ;// Eliminar el +1
    return contador;
}
```

Su método **retorna** un entero pero no lo imprime, solo hace la llamada al método `canciones.numeroCanciones()` en el `main`  , debe considerar modificar este método dado que `size` ya retorna la cantidad de elementos en el `ArrayList` y no es necesario añadir el **+1**, debería imprimir el resultado con

```
System.out.println(canciones.numeroCanciones());
```

El mismo problema tiene la opción 3 del `case` , debería ser

```
System.out.println(canciones.dameCancion(numero).dameTitulo());
```

> Cada vez que una función retorne *(return)* un elemento será necesario
>   imprimirlo para poder visualizarlo. A menos que solo desee asignar a una variable el valor devuelto.

Comment: muchas gracias compañero si era eso. ok gracias por la aclaracion

Comment: @JhonJamesHernandez Qué bien , tenga en cuenta la modificación de su método `numeroCanciones` , Saludos.